# GetValue by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

i want to get each ToolStripMenuItem of my MDI form's value by looping through them and using reflection as following:

```
FieldInfo[] menuitems = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.GetField | 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var item in menuitems )
  if (item.FieldType.Equals(typeof(ToolStripMenuItem)))
      MessageBox.Show(
        item.FieldType.GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(item, null).ToString());
```

but i got "Object does not match target type" error, i am confused and don't know what object to specify as the source object to get value of.

please guide me through...
thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a good use for reflection.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a case for reflection.

To get the menuitems, you should first get a reference to your ToolStrip and from there iterate over its `Controls` collection.

code would then look something like this:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in _myToolStrip.Controls)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Tag);
}
```

Comment: in this case i can not loop through all children wich has a specific tag value, cause there is a MenuStrip in MDI form called "MDIFMenuStrip

Comment: @bobby: If you don't have a reference to the menustrip in the first place, you should get it by iterating over a Controls collection at a higher level. (The MDI main window's Controls collection, picking up where the control is of the correct type or name)

Comment: is't it cleaner and more finicky to use reflection? could you help me using reflection?

Comment: No, reflection is NOT cleaner, and still isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

use something like `GetProperty("Tag").GetGetMethod().Invoke (item, null).ToString()` .

Comment: information you are providing is not enough... what are the types involved and which method is this part of ?